# IIS Express keeps running after debugging session is aborted

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I run my Web Interface in debugging mode and abort the session the Interface still remains running in IIS Express.

From other sources I have gathered that the setting under `Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Edit and Continue` has to be set on, which it is. I've also looked under the Project Properties as some sources suggested, but that doesn't seem to contain any `Enable Edit and Continue` option.

[image: Options]

How can I automatically stop the Interface when closing the debugging sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click at Your project, select properties go to "Debug" and there You have something like this:

[image]

Change it to settings similar to this:

[image]

This should stop app from running in IIS after stoping debuging.

Comment: Thanks. It works as far as closing the debugging sessions also closing the Interface, although the debug session doesn't run on IIS Express anymore